# Inventory Database: Merging Perpetual and Periodic inventory system

Tags: mysql, vb.net, database-design

My client ask me to create an inventory system that can of course print report daily, weekly, monthly and yearly.

So far, with this description I am able to do the system and the output will be something like this:

```
-------------------------------
|id|cost|price|quantity|profit|
-------------------------------
|1 | 10 | 12  |  100   | 200  |
-------------------------------
```

Then my client wants to have a beginning and ending quantity, that shouldn't be a problem, by just adding the items that have been sold and the remaining items. But my client wants to be able to reprint past data, let's say the report 5 days ago.

my database design is like this:

```
tbl_items
------------------------------------------------    
|item_code|item_name|item_cost|item_price|stock|
------------------------------------------------

tbl_sold
-----------------------------------------------------------
|id|item_code|item_cost|item_price|quantity_sold|date_sold|
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I improve my database design to meet my client needs?
How can I make the output like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
|id|beginning|cost|price|quantity|ending|profit|
------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a start you could set up a new table called tbl_item_transactions (or replace tbl_sold with this one). tbl_item_transactions would most likely contain the following fields:

- id
- item_code
- item_cost
- item_price
- transaction_type (if it is sale, delivery, disposal, or any other inventory movement)
- transaction_quantity
- transaction_amount (depending on the transaction type, could be item_price * transaction quantity, item_cost * transaction quantity, or transaction quantity * a computed average cost, or maybe a zero-amount transaction)
- transaction_date

This way you can account for all inventory movements including their effect. You can then make the queries based on transaction dates and item codes (or whatever the reporting requirement needs).